# meteor js: how to query for posts that have recently been rated?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Topics collection. Each Topic can be Rated. I denormalized the data so that the Topics collection stores the time of the most recent rating in "lastRated".

How do I query for all Topics that have not been rated in the last 6 hours?

My query right now looks like this:

```
var hoursAgo = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var beHereNow = new Date() - hoursAgo;
Topics.find( { 'lastRating' : {$lte: beHereNow} } );
```

However, when I run this in the console, I'm retrieving all the Topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the hours this way:

```
var date = new Date();
var beHereNow  = new Date();

beHereNow.setHours(date.getHours() - 6);
console.log(beHereNow); // Fri May 08 2015 10:09:32 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) 

Topics.find({ 'lastRating' : {$lte: beHereNow} });
```

Or better yet, you could use the **[momentjs](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment)** library, especially the [**`subtract()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) method:

```
var beHereNow = moment().subtract(6, 'hours');
Topics.find({ 'lastRating' : {$lte: beHereNow} });
```

Comment: Good call on suggesting momentjs! Great library.

Comment: @TimC You can say that again!